# request-pormise - bad post request to server with port

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I try use *promise-request* and write code:

```js
var pr = require('promise-request');

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/user/login',
  port: 4000,
  form: {
    login: 'login',
    password: 'password'
  },
  json: true
};
pr(options)
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

If don't use port options I got error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

And if I add *port* options error disappear but in official docs don't write about that you can set this option. And it is strage that it works because I set port in *uri*. I have error that I can not get data from server. I got only error:

```html
undefined:1
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I do same request with *http* module and all works good maybe I need use another module?

Comment: Are you sure you have working server on 127.0.0.1:80, to which you addressed your request? To run server on 80 port you must have sudo permission. For second error message you need to remove (for debugging purposes only) `json: true` and see what exact error you are getting.

Comment: I run server on localhost:4000 and don't use port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) or [request](https://github.com/request/request) instead of `promise-request`

Code will look like this:

1.

```
axios.post('/user/login', {
  login: 'login',
  password: 'password'
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

2.

```
request.post({
  url: '/user/login',
  form: {
    login: 'login',
    password: 'password'
  }
}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {

})
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80) using Axios. Any chance this isn't library related?